# Car Driving Behavior: using non-instant transition with a Markov Transition Matrix

Tags: r, probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have a dataset on driving behavior/trips (workable example below), with information on the departure location, arrival location, duration of the trip and length of the trip. The states of the location are: work, home and other. I want to model driving patterns of cars similar to a study mentioned below (but then with the inclusion of an extra non-instant transition) in R.

I want to use a non-homogeneous markov model where the likelihood of transition into another state depends on the current state and the time of day. From the dataset I have already developed a 15-minute interval markov transition matrix. However, I want to include a drive state (in between the work/home/other states) and a parking state (which is the work/home/other). With the drive time as a non-instant transition to make the behavior of cars more realistic. In this driving state there is a distance and duration for every combination between departure and arrival location. Unfortunately, my experience with markov models is a bit rusty.

Example code of the dataset

```
states <- c("Home", "Work", "Other")
arrivalState <- sample(states, 1000, replace = TRUE)
departureState <- sample(states, 1000, replace = TRUE)
travelTime <- sample(10:180, 1000, replace = TRUE)
travelDistance <- sample(5:200, 1000, replace = TRUE)


drivingBehavior <- as.data.frame(cbind(arrivalState, departureState, travelTime, travelDistance))
```

I am working in R, and ultimately I want to do a markov chain monte carlo simulation to simulate traveling and parking patterns.

How would I be able to include (and code) this non-instant transition?
In a way that I would also have the travel time and length per possible transition (e.g. work-home)?

The study as mentioned in the introduction:

*Shepero, M., & Munkhammar, J. (2017, October). Modelling charging of electric vehicles using mixture of user behaviours. In 1st E-mobility Power System Integration Symposium, Berlin, Germany (Vol. 23, pp. 2-7).*